# Building/Linking against Keg (/usr/local/opt) when normal brew package exists in /usr/local

Tags: c++, qt, homebrew

[MacOS Mojave 10.14.5, Xcode 10.2, ROS Kinetic, Qt 5.14.1]

I'm trying to build ROS Kinetic on my Macbook Pro. Certain modules within Kinetic utilise Qt, and I'm having a compilation problem because I have multiple versions of Qt on my system.

I have Qt v5.14.1, a Keg formula which is addressed(linked) through /usr/local/opt/qt, and Qt v4.8.7_6 which is addressed(linked) through /usr/local.  I don't want to unlink/uninstall either.

The particular package I'm having difficulties with is `qt_gui_cpp` which uses CMakeLists.txt files. (Though the package is actually a catkin package, I haven't had any issues using CMake functionality in the make files.)

I'm using Apple's Clang++ compiler, and I think that, based on the types of errors being reported, the compiler is finding the wrong include folder even though the paths in the compiler's error messages is correct for the version I'm using, under the hood.   I've tried using `set(CMAKE_IGNORE_PATH /usr/local/include)` but this hasn't helped.

The actual compiler command that is issued is below.  Note that `-I/usr/local/include` precedes the Qt v5.14.1 include, thus the compiler only looks into the Qt v5.14.1 folder when it can't find it under `/usr/local/include`:

```
    cd /Users/user/ros/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/qt_gui_cpp/src/qt_gui_cpp && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++
    -DQT_CORE_LIB
    -DQT_GUI_LIB
    -DQT_NO_DEBUG
    -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB
    -DROS_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=1
    -DROS_PACKAGE_NAME=\"qt_gui_cpp\"
    -Dqt_gui_cpp_EXPORTS
    -I/Users/user/ros/ros_catkin_ws/src/qt_gui_core/qt_gui_cpp/include
    -I/Users/user/ros/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/include
    -I/usr/local/include
    -I/Users/user/ros/ros_catkin_ws/src/qt_gui_core/qt_gui_cpp/src/qt_gui_cpp/qt_gui_cpp
    -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.14.1/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers
    -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.17_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7
    -isystem /Users/user/ros/ros_catkin_ws/src/qt_gui_core/qt_gui_cpp/include/qt_gui_cpp
    -isystem /Users/user/ros/ros_catkin_ws/src/qt_gui_core/qt_gui_cpp/src/qt_gui_cpp
    -iframework /usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.14.1/lib
    -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.14.1/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers
    -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.14.1/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers
    -isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers
    -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.14.1/./mkspecs/macx-clang
    -I/usr/local/opt/qt/include
    -L/usr/local/opt/qt/lib
    -fPIC
    -O3
    -DNDEBUG
    -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk
    -fPIC
    -fPIC
    -std=gnu++11
    -o CMakeFiles/qt_gui_cpp.dir/composite_plugin_provider.cpp.o
    -c /Users/user/ros/ros_catkin_ws/src/qt_gui_core/qt_gui_cpp/src/qt_gui_cpp/composite_plugin_provider.cpp
```

How can I resolve this problem without breaking other things?
(More info if needed.)